# runtime error 50290 method intersect of object '_global' failed

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, dropdown

I am new to VBA programming and struggling with following code which has the purpose to have a dropdownlist with multiple selection which is restricted to certain cells.
Problem is that when just the file with the VBA is open the VBA works fine.
When I open in parallel another excel file and try to use the dropdown lists I get the error note: runtime error 50290 method intersect of object '_global' failed (the error appears in If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("Mehrfachauswahl")) Is Nothing Then) I already searched for similar cases but did not find a proper solution.
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim OldVal As String
    Dim NewVal As String
    
    ' If more than 1 cell is being changed
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("Mehrfachauswahl")) Is Nothing Then
    
        ' Turn off events so our changes don't trigger this event again
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        NewVal = Target.Value
        
        ' If there's nothing to undo this will cause an error
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Undo
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        OldVal = Target.Value
        
        ' If selection is already in the cell we want to remove it
        If InStr(OldVal, NewVal) Then
        
            'If there's a comma in the cell, there's more than one word in the cell
            If InStr(OldVal, ",") Then
                If InStr(OldVal, ", " & NewVal) Then
                    Target.Value = Replace(OldVal, ", " & NewVal, "")
                Else
                    Target.Value = Replace(OldVal, NewVal & ", ", "")
                End If
            Else
                ' If we get to here the selection was the only thing in the cell
                Target.Value = ""
            End If
        Else
            If OldVal = "" Then
                Target.Value = NewVal
            Else
                ' Delete cell contents
                If NewVal = "" Then
                    Target.Value = ""
                Else

                    ' This IF prevents the same value appearing in the cell multiple times
                    ' If you are happy to have the same value multiple times remove this IF
                    If InStr(Target.Value, NewVal) = 0 Then
                        Target.Value = OldVal & ", " & NewVal
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True   
    Else
        Exit Sub 
    End If
End Sub
```

I searched in stack overflow and find similar problems, however as I am still a beginner I am not sure how the code must me to select "my active sheet"

Comment: Try `Me.Range("Mehrfachauswahl"))`

Comment: In a worksheet event handler you should use `Me` to reference the worksheet.  Events can be fired even when the worksheet is not active.

Comment: I tried already Me.Range("Mehrfachauswahl")) but there is still the same error note

Comment: Add this as first line in sub `MsgBox "Target=" & Target.Parent.Name & " Me=" & Me.Name & " ActiveSheet=" & ActiveSheet.Name`